# How to render jpg from the epl code response received from endicia

Tags: zebra-printers, epl

My Problem here is in my application I'm using endicia to ship international order.

All the labels I'm getting in response are being printed on zebra printer with size of 4*6 .

But shipping international orders, endicia sends very large labels which is not getting printed on 4*6 correctly. They suggested me to get response in epl encodeing.

Now when I'm getting this epl code can anyone help to render image out of this code.

Or is there any other way to get clear print out of international order label on 4*6 label using zebra printer.

The platform I'm using is PHP with code codeigniter framework.

Answer (score 0):

Is the response from endicia EPL or png?

Printing PNG to zebra printer is not great. There could be scaling problems. However, the way to do this is to do a normal print of png as a raster file.

If it is EPL, that should print directly.

The way I did this was to use shiprush sdk, because I send xml to shiprush, and it sends the epl to the printer itself, so I am free of that.